# facebook graph api returns error 2500 when there are commas in the id url

Tags: url, facebook-graph-api, escaping

I'm attempting to retrieve the "shares" graph data for a number of pages in JSON format. I suspect that the errors I am encountering stem from the fact that some of the URLs have commas in them, and are being parsed as an attempt to pass multiple ids.

Returns graph data.
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://celebritybabies.people.com/2012/08/23/backstreet-boys-howie-dorough-expecting-second-son/

Returns error 2500 "Cannot specify an empty identifier"
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.people.com/people/article/0,,20624518,00.html

Encode the commas, still returns 2500
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.people.com.people.article/0%2C%2C20624518%2C00.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to a way around it other than to use the normal inspection

`http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.people.com/people/article/0,,20624518,00.html`

You may have to file a bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs though I feel as the answer would most likely be "Status by design".

Comment: If you still want to query multiple at once, such calls can be [batched](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using FQL instead, querying the `link_stat` table:

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, comments_fbid FROM link_stat
  WHERE url = 'http://www.people.com/people/article/0,,20624518,00.html'
```

([See result in Graph API Explorer.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20url%2C%20normalized_url%2C%20share_count%2C%20comments_fbid%20FROM%20link_stat%0D%0A%20%20WHERE%20url%20%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.people.com%2Fpeople%2Farticle%2F0%2C%2C20624518%2C00.html%22)) You can also use `WHERE url IN ("…", "…", …)` to check multiple URLs at once.

This also returns a `comments_fbid` of 10151022112466453, and *that* one you can look up via the API, https://graph.facebook.com/10151022112466453

Maybe this can work as a workaround, until Facebook fixes this problem.